# C++ write to text file fast

Tags: c++, ofstream

I have a large amount of big matrices with values (integers) ranging from -1 to 15, which I want to write to a text file with the function below. The writing speed seems to be about 0.1 MB/s, so I have played around a bit to see if I can make it faster without any results. How do I make it faster?

```
bool mymap::write_one_mat(string txtfile, matrix& mat)
{
ofstream myfile (txtfile, ios::app|ios::binary);

int element;

if (myfile.is_open())
{
    int rows = mat.get_rows();
    int cols = mat.get_cols();
    myfile << "<";
    for(int i = 1; i <= rows; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <= cols; ++j)
        {
            element = mat.get_element(i,j);
            if(element < 0 || element > 9)
            {
                myfile << to_string(element);
            }
            else
            {
                myfile << " ";
                myfile << to_string(element);
            }
        }
    }

    myfile << ">\n";

    myfile.close();
    return true;
}
else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: No reason to use `to_string` here as the overloaded stream operators will handle the conversion for you and probably without any superfluous allocations.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code review.

Comment: You don't have to write `myfile << to_string(element);` in both branches, just once below both branches. You only need to write `myfile << " ";` in the false case and you don't even need an `else` branch.

Comment: There's no need for the `myfile.close()` call either and you may get better performance by turning off synchronization with C buffers by calling `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)` on the first line.

Comment: You might try writing everything to a stringstream and then writing the contents to the file all at once.  Even just constructing a line at a time and writing that might help.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Writing to a `std::ostringstream` first is unlikely to make the output faster: the file stream is already buffered and writing one large buffer instead of repeatedly writing the same buffer is bound to be slower due to the memory more likely being shuffled around.

Comment: @DietmarKühl While that may be true, I've found that minimizing the number of writes to a file can be an improvement in many cases.  Anyway, just a comment, feel free to ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

As was commented already, you may want to start removing the unnecessary use of `std::to_string()`: the stream can happily format integers directly. However, even when formatting integers directly, there is some unnecessary overhead finding about about facets which seems to use a `dynamic_cast<...>(..)` in most implementations. As a result it may be faster to format the integers manually using something like this:

```
std::locale loc(std::locale(), new std::num_put<char, char*>());
std::num_put<char, char*> const& np(std::use_fast<std::num_put<char, char*>>(loc));
char buffer[1024];
char* next(buffer);
for (int i(1); i <= rows; ++i) {
     for (int j(1); j <= cols; ++j) {
         int element(mat.get_element(i, j));
         if (element < 0 || element < 9) {
             *next++ = ' ';
         }
         next = np.put(next, myfile, ' ', element);
         if (std::numeric_limits<int>::digits10 + 1 <= (buffer + 1014) - next)) {
             myfile.write(buffer, next - buffer);
             next = buffer;
         }
     }
}
myfile.sputn(buffer, next - buffer);
```

Using `std::num_put<...>` directly seems to be the fastest approach (see [this graph](http://www.dietmar-kuehl.de/cputube/write-ints.html) which graphs the times taken for different compilers using different approaches: shorter is better).

It seems your code writes a large sequence of digits with some odd rule for introducing spaces: are you sure you don't want to put a space after each `element` and maybe a newline after each row?

Comment: Actually, this code seems to be significantly slower than my original one. I would expect something like this to be much faster... Maybe the problem lies deeper within my ancient computer and visual studios ;) Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Taking from the comments you have:

```c++
bool mymap::write_one_mat(std::string const& txtfile, matrix const& mat)
{
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::ofstream myfile(txtfile, std::ios_base::app | std::ios_base::binary);

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        int rows = mat.get_rows();
        int cols = mat.get_cols();

        myfile << "<";
        for (int i = 1; i <= rows; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= cols; ++j)
            {
                int element = mat.get_element(i, j);
                if (!(element < 0 || element > 9))
                    myfile << " ";
                myfile << element;
            }
        }
        myfile << ">\n";
    }
    return static_cast<bool>(myfile);
}
```

With the addition that `txtfile`'s and `mat`'s type has been changed to a reference to `const`. This makes sense since your `write_one_mat` method doesn't modify its parameters. Make sure that `mat::get_rows()`, `mat::get_cols()` and `get_element()` are `const` methods so they can be called on `mat`.

Comment: Most of the changes made no difference, but replacing `to_string(element)` with just `element` slowed it down pretty much, which I find a bit strange...